# qt cannot open input file 'c:\Qt\qt\lib\qtmaind.lib'

Tags: qt

I am using qt 4.5

I have created a project and I want to compile on visual studio 2008 for windows mobile 6.0
So I have created the project files doing this:

```
D:\Projects\Phone_PDA\Phone_PDA>set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2008
D:\Projects\Phone_PDA\Phone_PDA>qmake -tp vc
```

The VS project was created. However, when I try and compile I get this error:
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'c:\Qt\qt\lib\qtmaind.lib'

However, when I check my librarys and includes under project properties in visual studio. I have this:

```
Additional Include Directories
c:\Qt\qt\include\QtCore
c:\Qt\qt\include\QtGui
c:\Qt\qt\include
c:\Qt\qt\include\ActiveQt
debug
c:\Qt\qt\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008

Additional Library Directories
c:\Qt\qt\lib

Additional Dependencies
c:\Qt\qt\lib\qtmaind.lib
c:\Qt\qt\lib\QtGuid4.lib
c:\Qt\qt\lib\QtCored4.lib
```

However, when I browse to the directory c:\Qt\qt\lib all I have is:
qtmain.prl and qtmaind.prl
However, I don't have qtmaind.lib or qtmain.lib

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Are you using the commercial or open source version?

Comment: What do you mean, ``I don't have qtmaind.lib''?  I see it the list of what you have (3rd file from the bottom).

Comment: @scvalex I assume that it means they are listed in the project properties but are not actually on his system.

Comment: I am using the commercial version. I have edited my question, as I failed to suggest that I was listing from the visual studio properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the correct QMAKESPEC?

I would think you would need to use wince*-msvc2008

See [Qt: Supported Platforms](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/supported-platforms.html)

Answer (score 2):

Open the Visual Studio command prompt (you can find a shortcut in the start menu). It has all the appropriate environment variables set. Go to `C:\Qt\20****\qt`. Type `configure` and then `nmake`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the source distribution? If so you would need to compile Qt before you get the libs.

See:

- http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/install-win.html
- http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/install-wince.html

My commercial version comes precompiled. If I remember correctly, when I used the open source version I needed to compile everything myself.

Comment: I am using the commercial version. However, I have performed the same test on another computer that runs the same version of qt, and I got the same problem. When I browse to the C:\Qt\qt\lib I don't have the qtmaind.dll, Thanks.

Comment: There is a commercial source download as well. Sorry, but I can't think of a good reason why the files are not at that location. Do you have the exact name of the file you used to install Qt on the problem machine? I could check that against what I have at work on Monday.

Comment: Also, not being too familiar with the non-desktop (i.e. wince/windows mobile) installers, it is possible that they do not include those files because the target executable is handled differently on that environment. For example: VS thinks you are trying to create a desktop app (and trying to link accordingly) while your Qt install is targeting a wince app.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to configure the Qt to your machine to get the libs! It will takes several minutes. Follow the steps in: http://portfolio.delinkx.com/files/Qt.pdf

Answer (score 0):

in properties -> linker -> input

remove ANY path for qt libraries such qtmaind.lib

sometime you need remove :

/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS%40QMAKE_SUBSYSTEM_SUFFIX%40) from the VS project (under Properties --> Linker --> Command Line).

this is known BUG in VS addin