# Qt Visual Studio 2008 Add-in problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have Qt 2009.05 and Qt VS Add-in 1.1.3 installed on my computer with Visual Studio 2008. When I create simple Qt Application and build it, I'm receiveing this error.

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'qtmain.lib'
```

When I searched whole disk this file to add in Visual Studio library include variable, I doesn't find. I have qtmain.prl in my qt/lib directory but not qtmain.lib...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044882/qt-cannot-open-input-file-c-qt-qt-lib-qtmaind-lib

Comment: @nobugz: not really, that one tried to compile Qt apps for Windows Mobile 6.0

Comment: You are creating the vcproj as a Qt-project, not a regular Win32 project, right?

Comment: right, I'm creating Qt Application template from 'Qt4 Projects' project type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your qt\lib directory should contain all the lib files. You have probably downloaded qt source package  but you haven't built it. Download pre-built version for Visual Studio from [here](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008).

Comment: Indeed. Th qt/lib dir also contains a README saying "if this dir is empty, you probably didn't build Qt" or something similar.

Comment: I have downloaded from here: http://get.qt.nokia.com/qtsdk/qt-sdk-win-opensource-2009.05.exe it is compiled windows version.

Comment: qt/lib is not empty, there is .prl files instead .lib files. I'm in C:\Qt\2009.05\qt\lib directory.