# QT OpenSource, 5.12.1, default installation does not yield qtmainid.lib

Tags: c++, qt

Firstly, I would not post here because I did not look up questions and answers already relating to this. I have tried the solutions, to little avail, as most questions revolved around previous versions, and were vague in some way. Below are the pages I visited:

***Links***

https://forum.qt.io/topic/78962/how-to-use-qt-with-visual-studio-2017/13, this ruined my case even worse. Something temporarily broke down because of the last 2 steps, but was back again to normal after restarting QT.

[How to build Qt for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010), I have VS 2017, and the command line prompt for that doesn't recognize 'configure.exe'. This is the line of code:

```
configure.exe -release -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-ltcg
```

[Building Qt for Visual Studio 2010 - cannot open file 'qtmaind.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356975/building-qt-for-visual-studio-2010-cannot-open-file-qtmaind-lib), related again to VS 10, should I really work on the 2010 version? Is there a way to configure it for 2017, as it is the tool I am most familiar with?

[qt cannot open input file 'c:\Qt\qt\lib\qtmaind.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044882/qt-cannot-open-input-file-c-qt-qt-lib-qtmaind-lib?noredirect=1&lq=1), I have no idea what QMAKESPACE is. I just started yesterday with the intent of making my semester project in it, so I do not have any professional experience with QT previously, or any kind of experience in general. The link attached to the ticked answer, https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/supported-platforms.html, does not offer any kind of help. It just details what systems it supports. I am currently using Windows 10, version 1809.

https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/23917-fatal-error-LNK1181-cannot-open-input-file-qtmaind-lib, really lost me. Where are the qt sources that Nish is talking about? Are they from here: https://www.qt.io/offline-installers, from "Source Packages And Other Releases". Where are these files? Did they come with the installer from here: https://www.qt.io/download ? With what do I compile them with? Will these compiled files make some .exe files? Even more, these posts are from 2009.

***What Is The Problem?***

I watched the video by Derek Banas' series on QT ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I96uPDifZ1w&t=297s ). Here are the steps I took to set up QT:

i): Went to https://www.qt.io/download.

ii): Selected "Go Open Source", and then clicked on download

iii): Started the QT setup after download. In the packages menu, I selected 
the default. This gave me QT 4.6.3. 
iv): Made a new project as shown by Derek Banas.
v): Upon selecting the green arrow on the bottom left, with debug option chosen, I pressed it. It gave me the error:

```
LNK 1104: Cannot open file 'qtmaind.lib'
```

vi): Changed to release, profile, gave me this error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"in "".Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I tried reinstalling it. No use. I went here: https://www.qt.io/offline-installers, and download 5.12.1, the latest, plus the zip file in "Source Packages And Other Releases". Again performing the same as above, with the same errors.

Confused because the video did not address such an issue. Looked online. did not find much here, thus, I am here. My hypothesis:

i): This is something related to my path variables. Since both versions exhibit this issue, it means that fault is from my side, not QT's.

ii): Some windows .dll files are missing. But I do not know what files they are.

***Before You Answer***

Please just give me the directions I should move in to solve this issue. I do not have any idea where to go from here, but I really, really, really want to learn QT as part of my C++ learning, and I'm willing to work; I just lack the guidance.

If this is downvoted, please just send me some links which specifically address my issue so I can head over there. I would be very glad for the directions. :)

And lastly, thank you to all of you for reading through this wall of text!

Here are a few pictures of what I am seeing: [image: In Debug version]

[image: In Release version]

[image: List of compilers that QT detected]

Comment: What do you actually want? Just install Qt? I recommend using the online installer, it has always just worked for me. Only potential downside for you as Visual studio user is, it will use a bit of disk space and bandwidth to install Qt Creator.

Comment: It looks like your linker can't find the libraries and your app can't find the plugins. In the section *Build enviroment* ("Projects" tab in the left menu), check if the *QTDIR* variable is correct (It should be the path to your Qt directory).

Comment: @hyde, I want to run my project, when I do, I get the errors I mentioned above. That is, the LNK 1104 error when running debug, the windows QT platform plugin error not found when dealing with the release, profile. Trying to figure out why since I want to make a project in it. I have used the online installer, and the offline installer, both give me the same errors. It is not working for me on my first time. Also, I was confused about using VS in the first place. I've seen people use both the VS and the IDE within QT. Anyways, thank you for the reply!

Comment: By run, I meant pressing the green arrow on the bottom left as you can see. I want to see my current application as I have seen Derek Banas do.

Answer (score 1):

It finally worked!
If this is of some help to anybody out there, please **do not select** the default button at the installation phase. Depending on your time, please go ahead and select MSVC  64 bit, MSVS < 2nd Latest Version >, and MinGW < Latest Version > 64 Bit, that shows up at the installation time. This will allow you to use a different kit that you can use to run your application with. To access this kit, go to the green button, hover over it, or click it, and there will be a kit called, desktop QT  MSVC  64-bit, and then select this, and *then* run your program. This will run your program properly.